# RxNetty how to use onErrorResumeNext

Tags: rx-netty

I am facing a problem to get rest of items from observable after thrown an exception. Assume I have 10 items to emit, on second item, I throw an exception and my Subscriber onError got called with the exception thrown, after that, the rest 8 items will be emitted. How can i continue emitting the rest of 8 items to my subscriber (onNext) in here? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use onErrorResumeNext to tell your pipeline what to emit in case of Exception. Looks this Unit test example.

```
@Test
public void observableOnErrorResumeException() {
Integer[] numbers = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

Observable.from(numbers)
        .doOnNext(number -> {
            if (number > 3) {
                try {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }

        })
        .onErrorResumeNext(t -> Observable.just(666))
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

}

This code will print

```
0
1
2
3
666
```

You can see more examples here https://github.com/politrons/reactive

Answer (score 0):

Is the source emitting 10 items emitting an error or some operator in between? If the source is emitting an error then the resumption must be built into the source as there isn't an explicit contract in RxJava to resume.
If there is an operator in between that is emitting an error then that error has to be suppressed by something like `onErrorResumeNext()`. Looking at code makes it easier to comment.